# Python no reconoce el módulo "Telegram"

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

estoy teniendo un problema al querer utilizar el módulo `python-telegram-bot`, al querer importarlo obtengo el siguiente error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram'`. Sin embargo, el módulo está correctamente instalado, ya que si en la consola ejecuto lo siguiente:

```
$ python -m telegram
```

Me sale esto:

```
python-telegram-bot 13.9
Bot API 5.5
certifi 2021.10.08
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Aclaro que intenté descargarlo de varias maneras, utilizando `pip install python-telegram-bot`, `pip3 install python-telegram-bot` y descargandolo directamente desde el repositorio de git con

```
$ git clone https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot --recursive
$ cd python-telegram-bot
$ python setup.py install
```

Pero nada de lo anterior me dio resultado.

Comment: Ejecuto `pip install python-telegram-bot` y luego en la consola de python `import telegram` y lo hace sin problemas. ¿Estás usando enviroments, pyenv, anaconda, etc?

Comment: Tienes dos o mas versiones de Python instaladas?